# How to get HTML element in $mdDialog in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have implemented an $mdDialog in my angular app which is showed by the following code when I am clicking a button:

```
            // Show the dialog
        $mdDialog.show({
            clickOutsideToClose: true,
            controller: function($mdDialog) {
                this.item = item;
                this.close = function() {
                    $mdDialog.cancel();
                };
        var video = document.getElementById('video');

            },
            controllerAs: 'dialog',
            templateUrl: 'templateurl',
            targetEvent: $event
        });
```

In my templateurl is an HTML document with the following element

```
<video id="video"></video>
```

I am trying to get access to the video element via "document.getElementById" in my controller (see code). Since the controller is loaded before the html is rendered I get back a null object...

Did anybody already achieve this?

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a directive to put the element on scope:

```
app.directive("onElemLink", function() {
    return postLink;
    function postLink(scope, elem, attrs) {
        scope.$eval(attrs.onElemLink, {$elem: elem});
    }
});
```

Usage:

```
<video on-elem-link="videoElem=$elem"></video>
```

In the controller:

```
$scope.videoElem.on("load", function(event) {
    console.log(videoElem[0].videoHeight);
    console.log(videoElem[0].videoWidth);
});
```

The AngularJS framework invokes the postLink function of a directive after the framework adds the element to the DOM. This is the best place to implement code that depends on the existence of the element.

---

> I get the error "Cannot read property 'on' of undefined" in my controller at $scope.videoElem.on(..). I think this is because the code is executed no matter if the directive has been loaded?

Another way to use the directive is to supply a function:

```
<video on-elem-link="videoOnLink($elem)"></video>
```

In the controller:

```
$scope.videoOnLink(elem) {
    console.log("video element linked");
    $scope.videoElem = elem;
    $scope.videoElem.on("load", function(event) {
        console.log(videoElem[0].videoHeight);
        console.log(videoElem[0].videoWidth);
    });
});
```

The `videoOnLink` function is invoked after the [$compile service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) links the directive to the DOM.

Comment: Well your answer makes sense, thank you so far. Nevertheless, I get the error "Cannot read property 'on' of undefined" in my controller at $scope.videoElem.on(..). I think this is because the code is executed no matter if the directive has been loaded?

Comment: the function doesn't get invoked...I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: It works now. But I've done it with a workaround. I have set a button which gets on-click the video element. With that, I can assure that the video element is already in the DOM and not null.